# Using InputStream and InputStreamReader to create strings - Android

Tags: android, textview, inputstream

I have two strings of text being retrieved from an internet text file that are being shown in logcat that I want placed into strings for use in my layout.xml file for TextView. I am using InputStream and InputStreamReader and I would like the lines of text to be placed into a pre-defined string name to be used in a textView. Can anyone direct me on how this would be done or the method that could be used to have the text placed in a certain textView as the text needs to be easily edited without the layout of the text changing or the placing of the text on the string changing. Can someone guide me on how I would do this?